# Detecting an element is being resized with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

With CSS' resize rule, one can allow an element to be resized like so:

```
.someClass {
  resize: vertical/horizontal/both
}
```

However, I'm unable to find a way to detect an element is being resized.

HTML' Drag and Drop API has built-in events to detect dragging which are documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Is there a similar way I can detect when an element is being dragged, or make my own version?

Comment: @yousoumar This might help with some of the more complicated things I want to do. I'm surprised it wasn't one of the suggested similar questions when I was creating the question/post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the element by a selector. For example:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.someClass');
```

And then you can use `resizeObserver`:

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
     console.log(entry)
  }
  console.log('Size changed');
  
});

resizeObserver.observe(element);
```

For more resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver